# Is it correct my use of "Of which" in this sentence

Tags: grammar, nouns

I'm using it in a sentence like this one:

"there were "X" reports of which "N" were founded"

where I'm talking about Investigated reports of complaints or denunciations.

Comment: The usage is correct, but we more usually say "valid" or "validated" rather than "founded", although we do say "unfounded" in the opposite case.

Comment: The word 'denunciations' evokes mirth in BrE speakers. It sounds like something that was common in the 17th century but not since.